# Clearing a PHP page

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, content-management-system, multifile-uploader

I'm working with an async file upload tool called plupload.  I have everything set up and working the way I want on a standalone page, but I have a problem.  I'm transferring my code to a content management system that stores all per-page PHP in a database - it also parses the PHP snippets, I think, to check that everything's error free.

The problem is this.  I'd like to return a response on a successful upload.

On a standalone page, I use die('A response') and halt the PHP before the HTML section.  In this case, I can't, because the CMS will still give the rest of the page in full.

I need to submit the form to self, because I'm incorporating some non-javascript stuff for degraded form validation etc.

Does anyone have an easy solution?  I'm currently testing for any async response at all (after a post, I mean) and calling that a 'success' on completed upload, if you follow what I mean by that.  I don't really like it.  I wondered about forcing a server error on any non-success (if I can).  Would that be especially bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a technique inspired by the above MySQL suggestion.

plupload includes a FileUploaded event.

I'm generating a random number before firing the upload and posting that along with each file.  Once I'm done moving the file around at the server side (an email attachment, actually) - if the mail send is successful, I write a small text file using the random number as the name and 'success' or similar as the content.  Then, when plupload's FileUploaded is fired, I make a new async request to a small standalone PHP file, passing over the same random number, and it reads the file before unlinking.

Thanks again for the help.  Seems to work quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to overwrite the index.php file of your CMS, this will work.

- Rename the current index.php to something else.  We'll say 'cms.php'.  You may want to change the permissions so only your server can read from it.
- Create a new PHP file called 'index.php'.  We're using an [example from the include docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (#6) in the PHP manual.  Here's [the (modified) code](http://pastebin.com/VKvJA3KN).

  - *note: the indentation get's all screwy, so I'll pastebin it instead.  feel free to edit*

If at any point in any part of your site you want to fail it, you can just stick the real data in `$GLOBALS['failContent']`, and the user will never see any CMS generated output.

---

I'm not sure what effect `die` would have when doing this, but I believe it will prevent us from outputting anything... but I'm **not** sure.  Does anyone know?

Comment: I don't think I'm comfortable overwriting the index.php for this one feature, but that does look like something that could work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in php file

```
<?php
$uploaddir='../uploads/';
$uploadfile=mysql_prep($uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']));
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
 {
  $name=mysql_prep(($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']));
  $type=mysql_prep(($_FILES['uploadfile']['type']));
  $data=($uploadfile);
  $size= intval($_FILES['uploadfile']['size']);
  #echo $data;
  $branch=mysql_prep($_POST['branch']);
  $sem=mysql_prep($_POST['sem']);
  $query="INSERT INTO upload_file (name,type,data,size,created,branch_id,sem_id) VALUES ('{$name}','{$type}','{$data}','{$size}',NOW(),'{$branch}','{$sem}')";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  if($result){
      echo"<h2>file successfully uploaded<h2>";
      redirect_to(root."afterlogin/upload.php?spload=0112");
  }
  else{
      echo" the file you insert can't be uploaded";
  }
```

and include this to html file

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['spload'])){
 $upload_process="you have successfully uploaded your file. ";
 $upr=1;   

  }else{

    $upr=0;

 }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm not familiar with mysql_prep, but you've given me a couple of ideas there.